# pass variable in one function to another in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I pass the value `e.regid` into `tokenHandler` function. I tried calling the `tokenHandler` from `onNotification` and its working but I want to invoke the function from submit button so that I will get some other values also.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dr.Reminder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo3.png">
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email ID" id="username">
      <div class="bar">
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" id="mobile">
      <div class="bar">
        <i></i>
      </div>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Patient ID" id="pid">
      <div class="bar">
        <i></i>
      </div'<div class="bar">
        <i></i>
      </div>

      <button onClick='tokenHandler(regid)'> Sign in</button>
    </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var pushNotification;

      function onNotification(e) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

        switch (e.event) {
          case 'registered':
            if (e.regid.length > 0) {
              $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");

              console.log("regID = " + e.regid);

            }
            break;


      function tokenHandler(regid) {
        var email = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var mobile = document.getElementById('mobile').value;
        var pid = document.getElementById('pid').value;
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.in/temp.php?email=" + email + "&mobile=" + mobile + "&patientid" + pid + "&token=" + regid, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }

      function successHandler(result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:' + result + '</li>');
      }

      function errorHandler(error) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:' + error + '</li>');
      }

      document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
    </script>
    <div id="home">
      <div id="app-status-div">
        <ul id="app-status-ul">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This worked..!

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(){
    tokenHandler(e.regid);
});
```

Comment: Whenever you ask question, the least thing you  should do it to take the time to proper format your code and question. The _"formatting"_  of your code was really bad. And you should make sure that here are not obvious error contained like: `</div'<div class="bar">`  or the missing `}` which will prevent your whole js code from running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you need to remove the event onclick on markup. 
Then in onNotification create the event handler, something like this:

$("#buttonId").on('click', function(){tokenHandler(e.regid);});